# Intercept Https/Http Network Traffic from my windows machine

Tags: proxy, traffic, network-traffic

I am trying to figure out technology that we can use to intercept a specific request from my decide(laptop).
Example: I would want to validate the request(post, put, get) being made from my device to https://www.example.com. It can be even from a native application(windows in my case).

I would be happy if someone can help me with code snippet.
Please help !

Comment: If you're just looking for a tool to do this, see [Fiddler](https://www.getfiddler.com/). Or do you need to do it programmatically?

Comment: Yes, looking for some own solution to be implemented programatically.